# Syntax error running command from a script

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a problem running one command from a file.

When I execute command directly in terminal everything is working and software do it well. If I try to run it from the file, there is error with one file all the time.

If I run it directly in terminal with this command and full paths it is working:

```
/home/lukas/snap/bin/gpt /home/lukas/Desktop/automatic/test/resample_s2.xml -e -p /home/lukas/Desktop/automatic/test/resample_20m.properties -t  "/home/lukas/Desktop/automatic/outputs/processed.dim" /home/lukas/Desktop/automatic/inputs/S2A_MSIL2A_20170717T095031_N0205_R079_T34UCV_20170717T095631.SAFE/MTD_MSIL2A.xml
```

When I run this command from a script, it throws an error with an `xml` file.

```
#!/bin/bash

gpt=/home/lukas/snap/bin/gpt
xml= /home/lukas/Desktop/automatic/test/resample_s2.xml
properties=/home/lukas/Desktop/automatic/test/resample_20m.properties
output=/home/lukas/Desktop/automatic/outputs/processed.dim
input=/home/lukas/Desktop/automatic/inputs/S2A_MSIL2A_20170717T095031_N0205_R079_T34UCV_20170717T095631.SAFE/MTD_MSIL2A.xml

$gpt $xml -e -p $properties -t $output $input
```

The error is:

```
/home/lukas/Desktop/automatic/test/resample_s2.xml: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/home/lukas/Desktop/automatic/test/resample_s2.xml: line 1: `<graph id="Resample_Sentinel-2">'
```

I execute is as:

```
bash gpt_test.sh
```

But the `xml` file is the same in both cases; it is working properly processed in terminal, but there is an error when I try to run it from a script.

Comment: You could user this tool `sudo apt install shellcheck` to check script

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This line is the culprit:

```
xml= /home/lukas/Desktop/automatic/test/resample_s2.xml
```

You must remove the space after `=`. With the space, it tries to execute the right part of the assignment as separate command, which explains why it shows errors about "unexpected tokens" in the XML file.

Comment: I would like to ask one more short question. How should I write the command as a variable and then run the variable -> cmd=$gpt $xml -e -p $properties -t $output $input and then $cmd. I have tried so many combinations of quotation marks to have it as one line and there is still error.

Comment: To run a command and assign its output to a variable, use Bash's process substitution syntax; `myvar=$(mycommand arg1 arg2)`.

Comment: `s/process/command/`?

Comment: @Zanna Oh, right. Of course `$(...)` is command substitution, not process substitution. Thanks for paying attention (just too late to edit the comment) :D